# what is the sum of the digits of 111111x111111?

Tags: number-theory

I have just learnt that there are palindromic numbers that are formed by multiplying for instance 11x11=121, 111x111=12321 but I having difficulties getting the meaning of the question. Any assistance on how to answer this question will be highly appreciated?

Comment: What of the meaning of the question doesn't make sense?  Do you know what number $111111\cdot 111111$ is?  (It follows a similar pattern to what you described with $111\cdot 111$)  Do you know what a digit of a number is?  The sum of the digits of a number?  (for $12321$ the sum of the digits is $1+2+3+2+1=9$)  To assist in calculation, perhaps use the fact that the first several digits are the same as the last several digits in reverse order.  Also that $1+2+3+4+\dots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks a lot I have calculated its 1+2+3+4+5+6+5+4+3+2+1=36

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to type it into a [calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20digits%20of%20111111*111111).  The more clever way is to note that there are $6 \cdot 6=36$ pairs of $1$'s and when you do the addition part of the long multiply there are no carries.